# Large action and state spaces in reinforcement learning

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

In an MDP, I have an action space and a state space that are very large (exponential), in the order of $\mathcal{O}(m^n)$ for some $n$ and $m$.

I know that in such a situation, Deep Reinforcement Learning (DRL) uses function approximation to deal with such large spaces. For example, Deep Q Learning (DQL) uses Deep Q Network (DQN) to approximate the value function Q.

When I was trying to implement DQL using DQN I noticed that I need to specify the action and state spaces. However, just by specifying them, it takes a lot of time, especially when $m$ and $n$ are large.

Am I missing something or it is just it and we have to specify these large states anyway?

Comment: can you be more precise about your state space?

Comment: A state is simply a vector in $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}^n$. So we have $m^n$ states.

Comment: even m=256, n~=100000 would be a pretty reasonable state space, so im not sure what difficulties you're having

Comment: What do you mean? If I use a for loop to iterate the state space, I would take $\mathcal{O}(m^n)$, right?

Comment: why do you have to loop over all states in the state space? deep q learning doesn't require this